# Example 23 from Chapter 1, Hall and Knight's Higher Algebra.

Tags: ratio

I'm trying to solve the following,from Example 23 of Ratio chapter in Hall and Knight's Higher Algebra, 4th edition:

$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 3x^2 - 2y^2 + 5z^2 = 0 \\
 7x^2 - 3y^2 - 15z^2 = 0\\
 5x - 4y + 7z = 6 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

Solving equation 1 and 2 by cross multiplication, I got as far as :

$x^2/45 = y^2/80 = z^2/5$.

I'm not able to figure out how to solve the third equation in first degree with this information.

Thanks for the help. Apologies for the formatting...trying to learn Mathjax but am a beginner.

Comment: write $y,z$ in terms of $x$ using the equation you got, and putin third equation.

Answer (score 0):

Set $t=\dfrac{x^2}{z^2};\;y=\dfrac{y^2}{z^2}$

$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 3 t-2 u+5=0 \\
 7 t-3 u-15=0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

$t=9;\;u=16$

Thus

$\dfrac{x^2}{z^2}=9\lor \dfrac{y^2}{z^2}=16$

$x=\pm 3z;\;y=\pm 4z$

We have two systems

$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 x=3z \\
y=4z\\
 5 x-4 y+7 z=6 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

$x = 3,\;y= 4,\;z= 1$

$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 x=-3z \\
y=-4z\\
 5 x-4 y+7 z=6 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

$x = -\dfrac{9}{4},\;y= -3,\;z= \dfrac{3}{4}$

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot , this is a really neat explanation !

Comment: I found 2 more solutions I think so, $x=3/4, y=-1, z=-1/4$ and $x=9/19, y=-12/19, z=3/19$